# Possibilities of getting generating same number in different machine using RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: cryptography, numbers

I am exploring options to Generate 9 digit unique number without using database 
I have to run same application in multiple machines

if I use RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate number what are the possibilities of generating same number in different machine?

Comment: If you generate more that 10k IDs, collisions become likely.

Answer (score 1):

Nine digit numbers range from 000000000 to 999999999.  That is 1,000,000,000 possible values.  Your chances of a duplicate will be 1 in 1,000,000,000 for the second number picked.  2 in 1,000,000,000 for the third number picked and so on.  How many numbers do you intend to pick?

Comment: I have to pick all the numbers.

Comment: Then you need to use an encryption.  See my answer http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-numbers/1390#1390